# Does Django have a way for ModelViewSet to represent both parent and child models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to have extra fields in response **if they are available**, but not all objects of that class have this property. So for example we have

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = model.CharField()
    wheelcount = model.IntField()

class Truck(Car):
    max_load = model.IntField()

class Bus(Car):
    max_people = model.IntField()
```

and a view

```
class CarView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
```

And I want to have max_load and max_people when i check all available cars.

**Is there a way to either write CarSerializer to somehow serialize child objects differently, or a way to make view class choose a serializer based on class or additional field(like having an enum CarType)?**

Comment: What do you mean by "serialize child objects differently"? Different from what? What results are you looking for?

Comment: You can do it using the `to_representation` method within a ModelViewSet type serializer.  In addition, I wouldn't use inheritance, rather I would create a normal Truck and Bus model with a Car -> 1x1 relation. 

Like this you can do a inner join and display the data within the to_representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which fields you'd like to serialize normally in the meta class.

ex:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Car
         fields = [<whatever specific fields you want to serialize>]
```

if you need to serialize objects based on certain conditions you can use the `SerializerMethodField`.  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

From django rest documentation:

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on
> the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort
> of data to the serialized representation of your object.
>
> Signature: SerializerMethodField(method_name=None)
>
> method_name - The name of the method on the serializer to be called.
> If not included this defaults to get_<field_name>. The serializer
> method referred to by the method_name argument should accept a single
> argument (in addition to self), which is the object being serialized.
> It should return whatever you want to be included in the serialized
> representation of the object. For example:
>
> ```
>     from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>     from django.utils.timezone import now
>     from rest_framework import serializers
>     
>     class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>         days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
>     
>         class Meta:
>             model = User
>             fields = '__all__'
>     
>         def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
>             return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
> ```

in your case:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    object = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_object(self, instance):
        if instance.CarType:
            return <your desired object>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, because I need to get child fields from CarSerializer and Car does not have them, thus triggering AttributeError each time i want to get the field.